# Using preg_match to extract contents with PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using preg_match() to extract this - 
`Mostly dry. Very mild (max 16&deg;C on Fri afternoon, min 12&deg;C on Tue night). Winds decreasing (fresh winds from the N on Wed morning, calm by Wed night)` 
From this - 
`3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">Mostly dry. Very mild (max 16&deg;C on Fri afternoon, min 12&deg;C on Tue night). Winds decreasing (fresh winds from the N on Wed morning, calm by Wed night).</span>`

My code isn't working and just returns `Array ( )`

```
$contents = "3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">Mostly dry. Very mild (max 16&deg;C on Fri afternoon, min 12&deg;C on Tue night).
Winds decreasing (fresh winds from the N on Wed morning, calm by Wed night).</span>";

preg_match('/3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class=\"phrase\"> (.*?) </s', $contents, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is your friend, but if you are really want to solve this with preg_match you cpuld try this one:

```
$contents = "3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">Mostly dry. Very mild (max 16&deg;C on Fri afternoon, min 12&deg;C on Tue night).
Winds decreasing (fresh winds from the N on Wed morning, calm by Wed night).</span>";

preg_match( '@<span class="phrase">(.*?)</span>@s', $contents, $matches);

var_export( $matches );
```

**UPDATE:**

if you can't go for classes, try this:

```
preg_match( '@3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:.*?<span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">(.*?)</span>@s', $contents, $matches);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <span class="phrase">Mostly dry. Very mild (max 16&deg;C on Fri afternoon, min 12&deg;C on Tue night).
Winds decreasing (fresh winds from the N on Wed morning, calm by Wed night).</span>
    [1] => Mostly dry. Very mild (max 16&deg;C on Fri afternoon, min 12&deg;C on Tue night).
Winds decreasing (fresh winds from the N on Wed morning, calm by Wed night).
)
```

Comment: Actually I am scraping a web page and hence cannot use classes as they can be redundant. I have to use "3 Day Weather Forecast Summary" for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

For instance you want to match "Robert went." in "Robert Went.I never realized when.
" .You should use `preg_match()` in the following way:

```
$text = "<span style='color: #999;'>Robert Went.I never realized when.<br />";

$matches = array();

preg_match("/.*(Robert Went\.).*/", $text, $matches);
```

Comment: My match phrase won't be static. It would dynamic and would occur between `3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">` MATCH PHRASE  `</span>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are just removing all html code (the `span` tags) from the string (and the first part '3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:'). Why not detect all `<` and `>`? Something like:

```
$text = preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $text);
$text = trim(substr($text, strlen('3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:')));
```

The first line replaces all text within `<` and `>` (inclusive) by an empty string. The `?` is there to make it not greedy so that only *matching* `<` and `>` are removed.

The second line simply removes the leading string. Since it may or may not have leading spaces, I also included the `trim` function, but that may not be necessary.

Obviously, these two lines may also be combined into one line.